# How can I activate the container?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, binding

```
  package com.example.a230728_fragmentviewbinding

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate
import com.example.a230728_fragmentviewbinding.databinding.FragmentMainBinding


class MainFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

   private lateinit var binding: FragmentMainBinding

   override fun onCreateView(
       inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
       savedInstanceState: Bundle?
   ): View? {
       binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
     
       return binding.root
   }


   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
       binding = FragmentMainBinding.bind(view)
       setOnClickListener()
   }

   private fun setOnClickListener() {
       binding.container?.let { container ->
           container.children.forEach { btn ->
               btn.setOnClickListener(this)
           }
       }
   }


   override fun onClick(v: View) {
       when (v.id) {
           R.id.FragmentButton -> {
               Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
               //fragment의 context를 바로 요청.
               //Toast.makeText() 함수가 Context 객체를 필요로 하기 때문.
           // this를 사용하여 현재 Fragment의 Context를 가져오고 토스트메세지를 출력하는데,,
               //Fragment는 Context를 상속하는 클래스가 아니여서 this는 불가하다.
           }
       }
   }
   companion object {
       private const val TAG = "MainFragment"
       fun instance() = MainFragment

   }
}
```

binding.container?.let { container ->
container.children.forEach { btn -> // There is an error in this part.
Please tell me why the container is not activated and if so, where it is activated.!!

1. Unresolved reference: container
2. Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
3. Overload resolution ambiguity:
   public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
   public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections

//it's error

Comment: Can you add the code of `fragment_main.xml` to your question?